# problem with .Net xml importnode in powershell

Tags: powershell, .net, xml

Im trying to construct a powershell script that uses some XML. I have a XML document where I try to add some values with email addresses. The finished xml document should have this format: (I'm only showing the relevant part of the xml here)

```
<emailAddresses> 
    <value>bob@bob.com</value> 
    <value>kenny@bob.com</value> 
    <value>roger@bob.com</value> 
</emailAddresses>
```

SO, in powershell I try to do this as a test, which fails:

```
$newNumber = [xml] '<value>555-1215</value>'
$newNode = $Request2.ImportNode($newNumber.value, $true)
$emailnode.AppendChild($newNode)
```

After some reading, I have figured out that if I do this, it suceeds:

```
$newNumber = [xml] '<value name="flubber">555-1215</value>'
$newNode = $Request2.ImportNode($newNumber.value, $true)
$emailnode.AppendChild($newNode)
```

So, I am stuck. I'm starting to wonder if I should use another function instead of importnode when I have several keys with the same name but different values.

As you guys probably have figured out by now, i'm not an expert in xml. ANy help appreciated!

Comment: You might have better luck getting an answer on stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using:

```
$newNode = $Request2.createelement("value")
$newNode.set_innertext($newemailaddress)
$Request2.request.data.emailAddresses.appendchild($newNode)
```